# How to increase cell height and subview height at the same time with animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell with a subview inside it which on getting content from server increases in height once the response comes.

So I increase the height of this subview with animation, and on completion of the animation I send a delegate message to viewController.

in this delegate I set a instance variable with new value for the cell height and call

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

after that which just resizes the cell with new height with smooth animation.
but since this delegate method is called in the completion block of previous animation, it happens after it.

Is there a way to make both of them happen together smoothly ?

Comment: Did you try autoresizing the subview with respect to the cell?

Comment: but my problem is I will only know the height of the cell whe the subview resizes to new height or you are basically telling me to on getting the new height resize the cell with a delegate call and let subviews resize with autoresizing mask instead of setting the frame myself with animation?
hmm... I didn't try this, seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just

1) change the subview height directly without animation,

2) set the new cellHeight of the cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`,

and

3) update the table with animation. If do so, both the subview and the cell will animation correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSLayoutConstraint`..so that when a cell changes its height and width automatically its subview will also change its height and width.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:subView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                     multiplier:1.0
                                     constant:-5];

NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:subView
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                    multiplier:1.0
                                    constant:-5];

[cell addConstraint:myConstraint1];
[cell addConstraint:myConstraint2];
```

Adjust the `constant` according to your need.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Are these AutoLayout Constraints ?
I am not using AutoLayouts.

Comment: No...NSLayoutConstraint just defines the relation between the attributes(height,width etc) of two views

--

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html

Answer (score 0):

You ought to make animation in 1 animation function.
When you receive new height start animation(you can use layers transformation)